# Fix broken app icons in taskbar when launched from Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, start-menu

Windows-1 64-bit Home, 20H2

I don't know whether this is an issue with any specific version of Windows, but since the 20H2 update I chose to remove all my apps pinned to the taskbar and pin them to the start menu.

This is actually quite nice - I have 1 more action (invoke start menu) before clicking an app, but this is more than made up for by the greater space (hence navigability) of the start menu (if well organised) than that of the taskbar.

However, I have noticed that some applications, notably (but not exclusively) VMWare Workstation Player 16, Zotero, Veracrypt, Picassa 3) show only generic "dog-eared document" icons in the taskbar when launched form the start menu.

Icons can be persuaded to appear by pinning and then unpinning such anonymous apps from the taskbar.

What is causing this problem and is there a fix? NB icon caches were recently cleared but that has made no difference to the issue

**Update** A missing icon also reappears/disappears as the Taskbar setting *Combine taskbar buttons* is switched between *Always Hide* and *Never*

Comment: Unclear: Was VMWare Workstation Player pinned to the traybar before? How did you generate the Start menu icon and why was it necessary (the VMWare installation creates the Start entry it for you)? In any case, launching VMWare Workstation Player from Start does not give me a "dog-eared document" icon, so I don't understand what you did.

Comment: If the problem is just a thumbnail cache corruption, try the two methods from the article [Windows 10 thumbnails all messed up? Here's how to fix it!](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10).

Comment: If occurred for some applications, probably it was related to the compatibility with the latest OS version. Have you tried to reset the icon cache? 
https://winaero.com/fix-broken-icons-and-reset-icon-cache-in-windows-10/

Comment: @harrymc I was previously preferring Classic Start Menu; new start menu icons were created by using "pin to start" from the taskbar & the icons are now perfectly ok in the start menu - but sometimes that was not right 1st time (they also initially appeared (medium size) as document-ish icons) but changing size fixed that issue permanently. Issue with the taskbar occurs on every app start.

Comment: @Jenny I did say I had cleared icons and that it made no difference, but I tried the WinAero method too, just in case. Alas no difference.